# Statistical simulation in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve a problem given in the free online CS106B course from Stanford. The text of the problem shown below. I have written a function, but I'm not sure if the logic is right (not one of those programs when you know you have the right answer). Please see problem and my code below. I'd appreciate any feedback/suggestions.

PROBLEM:
Consider a 1000-voter election with a single percentage point spread between two candidates, i.e. 50.5% vote for one candidate, 49.5% for the other. The voting machine makes an error 8% of the time and records a vote for the opposite candidate than intended. Is this error rate high enough to invalidate the results of the election?
With a little knowledge of statistics, it is not hard to calculate the exact probability of an invalid outcome, but it is even easier to simulate this process. Generate a sequence of 505 votes for candidate A and 495 for candidate B where each vote has a 8% chance of being inverted when recorded. Do the vote totals result in B defeating A, despite the original intentions of the voters? This outcome represents one trial in the simulation. If you repeat this trial many times and keep track of the results, the ratio:

(number of trials in which election result was invalid)/(total number of trials)

provides an estimate of the percentage chance of an invalid election result.

Write a program that prompts the user to enter the voting simulation parameters, then performs 500 simulation trials and reports the ratio calculated above. A sample run of the program is shown below:

Enter number of voters: 10000 
Enter percentage spread between candidates: .005
Enter voting error percentage: .15 
Chance of an invalid election result after 500 trials = 13.4%

Your program should take care to verify the user's chosen simulation parameters are within range (percentages must be 0 to 1.0 and number of voters should be positive) and if necessary, re-prompt for valid input. Note that because of the randomness in the simulation, it is expected that the results will vary from run to run.

CODE (P.S. I used Stanford CPP libraries):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "console.h"
#include "gwindow.h" // for GWindow
#include "simpio.h"  // for getLine
#include "vector.h"  // for Vector
#include "queue.h"   // for queues
# include "random.h"
using namespace std;


/* FUNCTION PROTOTYPES */
void ElectionSimulation();


/* MAIN METHOD */
int main(){
    ElectionSimulation();
    return 0;
}

/* FUNCTION DEFINITIONS */

void ElectionSimulation(){
    int numVoters = 
        getInteger("Enter number of voters: ", 
        "You must enter a positive integer, try again");
    int numSimulations =
        getInteger("Enter the number of election simulations: ",
        "You must enter a positive integer, try again" );
    double voterSpread =
        getDoubleBetween("Enter spread between candidates, e.g. for 10%
        enter 0.1 etc: ", 0.0, 1.0);

    double votingError =
        getDoubleBetween("Enter vote recording error chance, e.g. for   
        15% enter 0.15 etc: ", 0.0, 1.0);


    // Determine the correct number of votes for each candidate 
    // given the spread and numVotes
    int correctVotesLower = numVoters*(0.5 - 0.5*voterSpread);
    int correctVotesHigher = numVoters*(0.5 + 0.5*voterSpread);
    int invalidElections = 0;


    // Run simulations
    for (int i = 0 ; i<numSimulations; i++){
        // Before every simulation, set the correct number 
        // of votes for each candidate   
        int votesLower = correctVotesLower;
        int votesHigher = correctVotesHigher;


        // Redistribute votes due to vote recording error
        for (int j = 0; j<correctVotesLower; j++){
            if (randomChance(votingError)){
                votesLower--;
                votesHigher++;
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k<correctVotesHigher; k++){
            if (randomChance(votingError)){
                votesLower++;
                votesHigher--;
            }
        }


        if(votesLower > votesHigher) {invalidElections++;}

    }

    cout << "After " << numSimulations << 
    " simulations, elections were invalid "
     << (double)invalidElections*100.0/(double)numSimulations
     << " percent of times" << endl;
}
```

In particular, if I enter the following parameters (as given in the problem text):

```
numVoters = 10000;
numSumulations = 500;
voterSpread = 0.005;
votingError = 0.15;
```

I get invalidElections around 30% of the time. Seems kind of high. The problem text says under these parameters i should get 13.4% approx (varies a little with each run due to randomness). I think my logic is faulty but I don't know where.

Comment: You've not explained the problem you're having with the code you posted, or asked a question. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Don't add information in comments. Instead, [edit] your post and add them there where they belong, in the question itself.

Comment: Can you add the `randomChance` function to your question?

Comment: Can you clarify what your voterSpread parameter is supposed to mean? If one candidate has 49.5 and the other has 50.5, should voterSpread be .005 or .010? Your code seems to assume the latter, but I'm not sure if that's what you intended.

Comment: "The voting machine makes an error 8% of the time " - Well - That explains Donald Trump and Brexit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your program is correct.

If people vote for candidate A with probability 0.5025, and the voting machine misregisters the vote with probability 0.15, then it means that the voting machine will register candidate A with probability 0.5025*(1-0.15) + (1-0.5025)*0.15 = 0.50175. When I plug this into the binomial distribution to find the probability of less than 5000 votes for A in 10000 votes, I find that the probability is about 0.36.

That's just a back-of-the-envelope estimate, not a correct calculation, but it shows that your 30% may not be too high.

(Update: Just to be sure, I also wrote a quick Python program that solves the problem using a different technique, and it also gives about 30%.)

Update 2: I woke up this morning with an idea for a way to compute the exact probability, and just had to try it out. So here's one way to find it with scipy;

```
import scipy.stats as ss

numVoters = 10000
voterSpread = 0.005
votingError = 0.15

correctVotersLower = int(numVoters*(0.5 - 0.5*voterSpread))
correctVotersHigher = int(numVoters*(0.5 + 0.5*voterSpread))

votersDifference = correctVotersHigher - correctVotersLower
minHighErrors = (votersDifference + 1) / 2

lowerErrorDist = ss.binom(correctVotersLower, votingError)
higherErrorDist = ss.binom(correctVotersHigher, votingError)

print sum([higherErrorDist.sf(x + minHighErrors) * lowerErrorDist.pmf(x) for x in range(0,correctVotersLower)])
```

The probability I get is approximately 0.305598.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know (i.e.  the statistical solution to the problem to cross verify the simulation result with.)

Comment: and yes, voter spread is the % difference between the leader and the underdog. If the votes are 0.49 vs 0.51 then the spread is 0.02.

Comment: If you want the exact theoretical solution, you could try https://stats.stackexchange.com/, I suppose. I'm more of a programmer myself, it's been a few years since I worked actively on statistics, so it would take me a while to figure out how to find the exact solution. But that's why we use computers anyway, right?